# Is there a way to solve an underdetermined linear system $Ax=b$ using the Fast Multipole Method?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I have an underdetermined linear system $Ax=b$. We may assume $A$ is full rank. The entries in $A$ satisfy the conditions for the Fast Multipole Method (FMM) to be applied, i.e. **the matrix-vector product $Ay$ can be computed very quickly.**

Is it possible to make use of the FMM to accelerate the solving of this equation? Is there any existing algorithm based on FMM for this?

Some remarks:

- The size $(m,n)$ of $A$ is very larger, in my current settings, $m\sim10000,\ n\sim100000$.
- Since the system is underdetermined, I hope the solution is the one that minimizes $\|x\|_2$.
- The main difficulty seems to be writing the equation in an iterative form.

Comment: Maybe you could use the conjugate gradient method on the problem $$\underset{x}{\min} \frac{1}{2} \langle Ax| x \rangle - \langle x | b \rangle $$ which will give you an iterative method $(x_n)_n$ to compute.

Comment: @Velobos The problem is that the system is underdetermined, so $A$ is not a square, the inner product of $Ax$ and $x$ cannot be computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum norm solution satisfies the normal equations $x = A^\top (AA^\top)^{-1}b$. If both the matrix-vector product $y \mapsto Ay$ and the matrix-transpose-vector product $y \mapsto A^\top y$ can be computed quickly, then $AA^\top y = b$ is a system of linear equations with a positive definite matrix and can be solved by the conjugate gradient method. The product $y \mapsto AA^\top y$ can be computed by composing the fast matrix-transpose-vector and matrix-vector products and is thus fast. Thus, you can compute $y = (AA^\top)^{-1}b$ using conjugate gradient and $x = A^\top y$ using the fast matrix-tranpose-vector product.

The conjugate gradient approach is only advised on speed and accuracy grounds if the matrix $A$ is well-conditioned in the sense that $\kappa(A) := \sigma_{\rm max}(A) / \sigma_{\rm min}(A)$ is modestly sized. The condition number of $AA^\top$ is the square of the condition number of $A$: $\kappa(AA^\top) = (\kappa(A))^2$. If the condition number of $AA^\top$ is large, the conjugate gradient method will take many iterations. If you can devise an effective preconditioner, this may help accelerate your method.

One might hope for a direct method which need not have an iteration count depending on the conditioning of $A$. I do not believe such an algorithm is known if fast multiplications by $A$ are computed by the fast multipole method. However, there are a variety of other FMM-related ways of representing and computing with a matrix $A$ with rank structure which may be worth investigating. This is a very broad and active field with many competing methods championed by different researchers. One possible low-rank structure to look into is the HSS matrix structure. If your matrix $A$ has not just FMM but HSS structure, I believe it's almost certain the $ULV$ factorization approach of [Xi and coauthors](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/120895755?casa_token=4pX2sv0yloYAAAAA:gDl-0KvURAeDjpKFAb16tlMSIHxrUbR9JuPJRM0qvRjIrr_FY3qR4XukzH7O4LFMKfVpuBVXRCs) can be adapted to the minimum-norm case (the original algorithm is in the least-squares context).